# How to pass arguments to Shell Script through docker run

Tags: bash, shell, docker, command-line-arguments

I am new to the docker world. I have to invoke a shell script that takes command line arguments through a docker container.
Ex: My shell script looks like:

```
#!bin/bash
echo $1
```

Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
COPY ./file.sh /
CMD /bin/bash file.sh
```

I am not sure how to pass the arguments while running the container

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use the same `file.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

Build the image using the existing Dockerfile:

```
docker build -t test .
```

Run the image with arguments `abc` or `xyz` or something else.

```
docker run -ti --rm test /file.sh abc

docker run -ti --rm test /file.sh xyz
```

Comment: I think ENTRYPOINT is the way to go if you don't want the end-user to know about file.sh directly.

Comment: How can you just start a script like this `docker run -ti test /file.sh abc`. I feel that the script wont run because it should be `docker run -ti test sh /file.sh abc`. sh or /bin/sh will run it right.

Comment: For anyone else coming here. The /usr/bin/env trick is optional style preference not a requirement of getting this to work. Also the #! line indicates which interpreter to use buy default. So it can run just by calling the script.

Comment: Also, with the given syntax for CMD, `/bin/sh -c` is the default entrypoint: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact

Answer (score 311):

with this script in `file.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Your container args are: "$@"
```

and this `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
COPY ./file.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/file.sh"]
```

you should be able to:

```
% docker build -t test .
% docker run test hello world
Your container args are: hello world
```

Comment: If you forget the "" around "/file.sh" as I did, it won't work.

Comment: for some reason, this doesnt work with `ENTRYPOINT ./file.sh`

Comment: Don't forget to `chmod +x file.sh` to set the executable flag.

Comment: @kev , do you know why is it like that? what's the difference between `["/file.sh"]` and `/file.sh` or even `[/file.sh]`

Comment: @Nitzankin see my answer for why proper json formatting is needed.

Comment: The short answer is one is a list of cmd + params to exec, while the other is a shell command to run. And only the exec form allows passing extra arguments from `docker run`. Details: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Answer (score 85):

There are a few things interacting here:

1. `docker run your_image arg1 arg2` will replace the value of `CMD` with `arg1 arg2`. That's a full replacement of the CMD, not appending more values to it. This is why you often see `docker run some_image /bin/bash` to run a bash shell in the container.
2. When you have both an ENTRYPOINT and a CMD value defined, docker starts the container by concatenating the two and running that concatenated command. So if you define your entrypoint to be `file.sh`, you can now run the container with additional args that will be passed as args to `file.sh`.
3. Entrypoints and Commands in docker have two syntaxes, a string syntax that will launch a shell, and a json syntax that will perform an exec. The shell is useful to handle things like IO redirection, chaining multiple commands together (with things like `&&`), variable substitution, etc. However, that shell gets in the way with signal handling (if you've ever seen a 10 second delay to stop a container, this is often the cause) and with concatenating an entrypoint and command together. If you define your entrypoint as a string, it would run `/bin/sh -c "file.sh"`, which alone is fine. But if you have a command defined as a string too, you'll see something like `/bin/sh -c "file.sh" /bin/sh -c "arg1 arg2"` as the command being launched inside your container, not so good. See [the table here for more on how these two options interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact)
4. The shell `-c` option only takes a single argument. Everything after that would get passed as `$1`, `$2`, etc, to that single argument, but not into an embedded shell script unless you explicitly passed the args. I.e. `/bin/sh -c "file.sh $1 $2" "arg1" "arg2"` would work, but `/bin/sh -c "file.sh" "arg1" "arg2"` would not since `file.sh` would be called with no args.

Putting that all together, the common design is:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
COPY ./file.sh /
RUN chmod 755 /file.sh
# Note the json syntax on this next line is strict, double quotes, and any syntax
# error will result in a shell being used to run the line.
ENTRYPOINT [ "/file.sh" ]
```

And you then run that with:

```
docker run your_image arg1 arg2
```

There's a fair bit more detail on this at:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example

Comment: I had experimented with setting my entrypoint to `["bash", "--login", "-c"]` to get the /etc/profile source in the image, but was later left wondering why no args would be passed to a shell script passed to docker run... Your answer cleared that up, thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ENTRYPOINT ["/file.sh"]`, i.e., with the preceding `/`?

Answer (score 70):

With Docker, the proper way to pass this sort of information is through environment variables.

So with the same Dockerfile, change the script to

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $FOO
```

After building, use the following docker command:

```
docker run -e FOO="hello world!" test
```

Comment: Why is this the highest voted answer?  Env vars are another way to pass info, but isn't what OP is asking.  And of course there is absolutely nothing improper about OP's desire to pass args to the container.

Comment: There's a ton of XY problems ask on SO. Since the OP stated they were new to Docker, it's perfectly reasonable an answer show the recommended way to achieve a goal. Thus making this a great answer.

Comment: Simplest way to get the job done instead of passing the variables as build args and all that mess. Very useful for passing secrets as environment variables.

Comment: I had a tricky situation where I needed a parameter with spaces in it to be passed through to a command inside the entrypoint. `pytest -m "not longest"` This was the only solution that worked for me. "Proper" or not, I'm glad it was here.

Answer (score 30):

What I have is a script file that actually runs things.  This scrip file might be relatively complicated.  Let's call it "run_container".  This script takes arguments from the command line:

```
run_container p1 p2 p3
```

A simple run_container might be:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "argc = ${#*}"
echo "argv = ${*}"
```

What I want to do is, after "dockering" this I would like to be able to startup this container with the parameters on the docker command line like this:

```
docker run image_name p1 p2 p3
```

and have the run_container script be run with p1 p2 p3 as the parameters.

This is my solution:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.io/ubuntu
ADD run_container /
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/run_container \"$@\"", "--"]
```

Comment: Replacing the third value in the `ENTRYPOINT` array with `"/run_container \"$@\""` means arguments containing spaces are handled correctly (e.g. `docker run image_name foo 'bar baz' quux`).

Comment: After adding switch/case statements to my bash file, ENTRYPOINT["run_container.sh"] no longer worked for me, but ENTRYPOINT["sh", "-c", "run_container.sh"] would no longer accept my parameters. This solution (with @davidchambers suggestion) worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to run it @build time :

```
CMD /bin/bash /file.sh arg1
```

if you want to run it @run time :

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
CMD ["/file.sh", "arg1"]
```

Then in the host shell

```
docker build -t test .
docker run -i -t test
```

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT` is a good answer for the OP who I think wanted runtime, but if you really want build time variables this answer just is broken.  Use `ARG` and `docker build --build-arg` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to use the string version of ENTRYPOINT so I could use the interactive shell.

```
FROM docker.io/ubuntu
...
ENTRYPOINT python -m server "$@"
```

And then the command to run (note the `--`):

```
docker run -it server -- --my_server_flag
```

The way this works is that the string version of `ENTRYPOINT` runs a shell with the command specified as the value of the `-c` flag. Arguments passed to the shell after `--` are provided as arguments to the command where `"$@"` is located. See the table here: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html

(Credit to @jkh and @BMitch answers for helping me understand what's happening.)

Answer (score -1):

Another option...

**To make this works**

```
docker run -d --rm $IMG_NAME "bash:command1&&command2&&command3"
```

**in dockerfile**

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**in entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

entrypoint_params=$1
printf "==>[entrypoint.sh] %s\n" "entry_point_param is $entrypoint_params"

PARAM1=$(echo $entrypoint_params | cut -d':' -f1) # output is 1 must be 'bash' it     will be tested    
PARAM2=$(echo $entrypoint_params | cut -d':' -f2) # the real command separated by     &&

printf "==>[entrypoint.sh] %s\n" "PARAM1=$PARAM1"
printf "==>[entrypoint.sh] %s\n" "PARAM2=$PARAM2"

if [ "$PARAM1" = "bash" ];
then
    printf "==>[entrypoint.sh] %s\n" "about to running $PARAM2 command"
    echo $PARAM2 | tr '&&' '\n' | while read cmd; do
        $cmd
    done    
fi
```

Comment: some remarks and limitations.... command with ":" needs changes in cut -d':' and commands like docker run -d --rm $IMG_NAME "bash:echo $PATH" will show the host path value instead the host one