# Docker passing in a variable into an shell script running git clone

Tags: git, bash, shell, docker, environment-variables

I am creating a Dockerfile and as part of this file, I am wanting to give the end user the option to pass in their git repo.

I looked at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727594/how-to-pass-arguments-to-shell-script-through-docker-run), and a few other sites but am stuck on the `git clone` syntax.

The git clone command returns an error as the variable that is part of it does not contain a value at the `docker build` stage.

I have this bash script called gitclone.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
git clone $1 /app
```

and in my Dockerfile I have this line:

`RUN ./gitclone.sh $LOCATION`

The shell script has the right permissions to run and it works when running it from within the container since I am passing an actual repository to it.

During the Docker build phase I get the following error:

> fatal: repository '/app' does not exist

The directory is there, but the `$1` is empty to the command doesn't work.

**Question**
How do I make the Dockerfile work? The desired output I want it:

`docker run -e LOCATION=https://github.com/something.git -d jwknz/pg02`

**UPDATE**
Changing my Dockerfile to contain
`CMD ["../gitclone.sh","$LOCATION"]` instead of `RUN ./gitclone.sh $LOCATION` doesn't fix it.

The Dockerfile will build, but the container stops after running the `docker run` command.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, the `Dockerfile` tells Docker how to build the image, and `docker run` starts a new container from the already build image. The `RUN` command is executed during the building of the image. Do you pretend to have the environment variable passed to the run command during the building of the image, or am I missing something?

Comment: What I want is for docker run to take a git URL and clone it at docker run, but want to pass it in using the -e parameter

Comment: OK. Then, you don't want to clone the repo during the building of the image but during the start of a container from it. You can define an entrypoint.sh script that is executing when a container is started. I'll try to document this a bit in an answer.

Comment: `$1` is _shell_ syntax.  Dockerfiles are completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you have to notice that the `Dockerfile` is used to build your image (with the `docker build` command) and `docker run` is used to start a container from the already build docker image.

You have to define an *entrypoint* script. This is a script that is executed every time a container is started from the image you've build with the `Dockerfile`.

Assuming you want to clone a git repo and run apache httpd afterwards you can create a script like this in the same folder where your `Dockerfile` is. Name it, e.g. `gitCloneAndRunHttpd.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash 

git clone $LOCATION /app 
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -f /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

Then you have to modify your `Dockerfile` telling docker to copy the script file to your docker image, make it executable, en tell it to run it at container creation:

```
[...]

COPY ["gitCloneAndRunHttpd.sh", "/gitCloneAndRunHttpd.sh"]
RUN chmod +x /gitCloneAndRunHttpd.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/gitCloneAndRunHttpd.sh"]
```

After this you build your docker image with the docker `build` command and then you can start creating containers from your image.

Every time you start a container from it with `docker run -e LOCATION=https://github.com/some-git-repo.url -d your/image`, the repo *https://github.com/some-git-repo.url* will be cloned from within the container to the /app folder and apache httpd will be started.

Note: If you are wondering what is going on in the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727594/how-to-pass-arguments-to-shell-script-through-docker-run) you mentioned, there the default *entrypoint* is used (/bin/sh), and `/file.sh abc` is the argument passed to that *entrypoint*, therefore the `file.sh` script is executed.

Comment: I have been having a play with it for a while and I keep getting an `exit` status after I run the command.
`Exited (128) 2 seconds ago` and the container won't start after it

Comment: Also how does the `ENTRYPOINT ` know what parameter to use? What if I have 2 shell scripts?

Comment: Do you get an error building the image or starting a container?

Comment: The building works fine and running doesn't return an error, but the container exits when the script is completed

Comment: A docker container always exists when the main process finishes. What should you container do after cloning the the repo? Does it clone the repo?

Comment: Yeah, but how do I get around that? Like how do I let a user import their own git repo at the docker run stage? Or is that impossible?

Comment: The entrypoint scripts receives as parameters all what follow the docker image name in the run command (at the end of the command), but you can also use environment variables like you did with -e

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145823/discussion-between-manuel-schmidt-and-jeff-kranenburg).