# How to pass dynamic values to Docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am running a perl script in `Dockerfile` and I would like to pass dynamic command line arguments to the perl script while running docker image(container).
***Ex:*** `CMD perl test.pl <args>`. I am new to Docker.

Is there any possible way to pass dynamic values to the docker container like
`docker run <image name> <args>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an Entrypoint script:

> $ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]

and

> If the image also specifies an ENTRYPOINT then the CMD or COMMAND get appended as arguments to the ENTRYPOINT.

So depending on your `Dockerfile` you'd have something like this (python sample app):

```
FROM jfloff/alpine-python:3.6

# add entrypoint script
USER root
COPY start.sh /
RUN chmod a+x /start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
CMD ["arg1"]
```

and `start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1

# don't exit
/usr/bin/tail -f /dev/null
```

Now you can do something like:

```
15:19 $ docker run f49b567f05f1 Hello
Hello
15:21 $ docker run f49b567f05f1
arg1
```

Now if your script is set up to take those arguments, you should be able to run it as you want. Reference from Docker is attached, search for *"Overriding Dockerfile image defaults"* in [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) and then look in the *CMD* section.

Or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727594/how-to-pass-arguments-to-shell-script-through-docker-run) Post.

Comment: Thank you for your help and document. I could find answers for my questions with the document.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether you can do it with `CMD` but if you just want to execute the perl script with some passed in arguments use `ENTRYPOINT`.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["perl", "test.pl"]
CMD ["default-arg"]
```

Run the container with:

```
docker -run <image-name> overriding-arg
```

Comment: Thank you, it is useful for me.

Comment: I'm glad it helped