# ssh credentials in docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, ssh, docker-compose

I have an application running properly with `docker-compose up`. That application connects using SSH to my host machine and executes some commands. Right now I provide the SSH credentials by writing them in the source code like this:

```
const pass = 'mypassword';
let username = 'myusername';
let host = '172.17.0.1';
```

I 'm trying to follow [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2) guide in order to provide the credentials in a better way. I cannot understand how this line works `privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('/here/is/my/key')` Is it a relative path, is the "key" a file with the password as plain text? Is there something I should provide from my host machine? How can I give the credentials in a docker container?

Comment: set as env vars, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494050/how-do-i-pass-environment-variables-to-docker-containers

Comment: ok I will create a .env file and write there the credentials. After that I will change the docker-compose file. But what changes I have to do in the code?

Comment: I did it with this: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786 . thanks.

Comment: In the guide, they want you to mount a directory with your private key from the host machine.

Comment: as a docker volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, to pass in parameters into a container to be read by your Node.js script, you can:

- Leverage environment variables (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file)
- Mount a directory from the host system into the running container using volumes (https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)
- Pass them as parameters ([How to pass arguments to Shell Script through docker run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727594/how-to-pass-arguments-to-shell-script-through-docker-run)).
- Download them from a remote server

For secret data such as SSH credentials, I would **advise against** using arguments or environment variables because they can be inspected from various sources. This article explains well why: https://diogomonica.com/2017/03/27/why-you-shouldnt-use-env-variables-for-secret-data/

Instead, I would create a simple configuration file that your Node.js script can read.

```
{
   "username": "myuser",
   "password": "pass",
   "host": "172.17.0.1",
   ...
}
```

You can put this file a directory on your host system and mount it under `/myvolume` to the container when you start your container:

```
docker run -it -v host-directory:/myvolume myimage
```

Your Node.js script now can read the JSON file:

```
const configFilePath = "/myvolume/secret-config.json"
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configFilePath));

// now you can use config.host, config.username and config.password
```

As a side note: I recommend setting up your remote SSH server to use private/public key authentication since passwords generally less secure. Once you have set up private/public key authentication, you can put the private key file in the same volume and load it from your Node.js script in a similar way :)

Comment: so if I want to pass username, password, host-ip, as I already did with a .env file, I should use 3 secret-config.json files?

Comment: You can also work with an```.env``` file using ```dotenv``` instead of a JSON file. In either case, you would pass all three parameters in one file, not three files.

Comment: Although .env files are great, I personally would not use it in this specific case. It would enable other developers (who might maintain the code after me) to use it less securely (with environment variables).

Comment: so the concept is to use a volume to keep the file in the host machine right? For security reasons?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to keep private data like hostname, username, password away from command outputs like ```ps```. You can learn about this more here: https://diogomonica.com/2017/03/27/why-you-shouldnt-use-env-variables-for-secret-data/

Comment: This also assumes that you keep the file itself safe, such as not running any processes inside the container as root and set proper file permissions.

Comment: I just realized you didn't try to connect using a private key but want to use username and password instead. While it it generally more secure to use a private/public key pair to authenticate with an SSH server, I updated my answer to fit your question better.

Comment: It's working! is it possible to run it with docker compose up?

Comment: Yes, very similar! Instead of passing the volume definition via the command line you need to pass it via the docker-compose.yaml file. See here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference

Comment: Fine. I did it. Thank you.