# screen command doesn't work in a container

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I'm playing with Docker lately and I decided to start a little fun project so I have this Dockerfile :

```
# Base Image
FROM debian:buster

# Making steam directory
RUN mkdir /home/cs &&\
    mkdir /home/Resources &&\
    mkdir /home/Resources/steamcmd &&\
    mkdir /home/Resources/rehlds &&\
    mkdir /home/Resources/metamod &&\
    mkdir /home/Resources/amxmodx &&\
    mkdir /home/Resources/reunion &&\
    mkdir /home/Resources/rechecker &&\
    mkdir /home/Resources/reaimdetector &&\
    mkdir /home/Resources/cstrikefix &&\
    mkdir /home/Resources/regamedll &&\
    mkdir /home/Resources/reapi &&\
    mkdir /root/.steam &&\
    mkdir /root/.steam/sdk32 &&\
# Installing required packages
    dpkg --add-architecture i386 &&\
    apt-get update -y &&\
    apt-get install -y libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 lib32gcc1 curl tmux screen xz-utils unzip unrar-free nano &&\
# Installing the server
    cd /home/Resources/steamcmd &&\
    curl -sqL "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz" | tar zxvf - &&\
    until ./steamcmd.sh +login anonymous +force_install_dir /home/cs +app_update 90 -beta beta validate +quit; do sleep 1; done &&\
# Fix steamclient.so issue
    cp /home/cs/steamclient.so /root/.steam/sdk32/ &&\
# reHLDS patch
    cd /home/Resources/rehlds &&\
    curl -sqL "http://nexus.rehlds.org/nexus/content/repositories/rehlds-dev/rehlds/rehlds/3.7.0.693-dev/rehlds-3.7.0.693-dev.zip" >> rehlds-3.7.0.693-dev.zip &&\
    unzip rehlds-3.7.0.693-dev.zip &&\
    cp -r bin/linux32/* /home/cs/ &&\
# Metamod
    cd /home/Resources/metamod &&\
    curl -sqL "http://teamcity.rehlds.org/guestAuth/downloadArtifacts.html?buildTypeId=Metamod_Publish&buildId=lastSuccessful" >> Metamod_publish_1.3.0.128_artifacts.zip &&\
    unzip -q Metamod_publish_1.3.0.128_artifacts.zip &&\
    unzip -q metamod_1.3.0.128.zip &&\
    cp -r addons /home/cs/cstrike &&\
    sed -i 's+gamedll_linux "dlls/cs.so"+gamedll_linux "addons/metamod/metamod_i386.so"+g' /home/cs/cstrike/liblist.gam &&\
# AmxModX
    cd /home/Resources/amxmodx &&\
    curl -sqL "https://www.amxmodx.org/release/amxmodx-1.8.2-base-linux.tar.gz" | tar zxvf - &&\
    curl -sqL "https://www.amxmodx.org/release/amxmodx-1.8.2-cstrike-linux.tar.gz" | tar zxvf - &&\
    cp -r addons /home/cs/cstrike/ &&\
    echo "linux addons/amxmodx/dlls/amxmodx_mm_i386.so" >> /home/cs/cstrike/addons/metamod/plugins.ini &&\
# Reunion
    cd /home/Resources/reunion &&\
    curl -sqL "http://repository.btstelecom.ro/resources/reunion_0.1.92.zip" >> reunion_0.1.92.zip &&\
    unzip reunion_0.1.92.zip &&\
    mkdir /home/cs/cstrike/addons/reunion &&\
    mkdir /home/cs/cstrike/addons/reunion/dlls &&\
    cp bin/Linux/reunion_mm_i386.so /home/cs/cstrike/addons/reunion/dlls/ &&\
    cp reunion.cfg /home/cs/cstrike/ &&\
    echo "linux addons/reunion/dlls/reunion_mm_i386.so" >> /home/cs/cstrike/addons/metamod/plugins.ini &&\
# ReChecker
    cd /home/Resources/rechecker &&\
    curl -sqL "https://amxx-bg.info/download/file.php?id=1444&sid=1811ca41ee4e4a17ea7110eecd7954a6" >> rechecker_2_5.zip &&\
    unzip -q rechecker_2_5.zip &&\
    mkdir /home/cs/cstrike/addons/rechecker &&\
    mkdir /home/cs/cstrike/addons/rechecker/dlls &&\
    cp bin/addons/rechecker/rechecker_mm_i386.so /home/cs/cstrike/addons/rechecker/dlls/ &&\
    cp bin/addons/rechecker/resources.ini /home/cs/cstrike/addons/rechecker/dlls/ &&\
    echo "linux addons/rechecker/dlls/rechecker_mm_i386.so" >> /home/cs/cstrike/addons/metamod/plugins.ini &&\
# cstrike fix
    cd /home/Resources/cstrikefix &&\
    mkdir /home/cs/cstrike/addons/cstrike &&\
    mkdir /home/cs/cstrike/addons/cstrike/dlls &&\
    curl --header "Host: c-s.net.ua" --header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36" --header "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" --header "Accept-Language: ro-RO,ro;q=0.9,en;q=0.8" --header "Referer: https://c-s.net.ua/forum/topic81470.html" --header "Cookie: _ga=GA1.3.1603347949.1602960053; __gads=ID=f426b07af5c143a1-22526794ffb800af:T=1603190043:RT=1603190043:S=ALNI_MaFPky-pOiwPIbZanyNiU0Ksdqm0Q; session_id=9fb1924d44b7d5b77af02e9680400c4f; topicsread=a%3A4%3A%7Bi%3A17628%3Bi%3A1603190043%3Bi%3A84615%3Bi%3A1604348502%3Bi%3A81470%3Bi%3A1604348492%3Bi%3A74614%3Bi%3A1603821602%3B%7D; _gid=GA1.3.999712779.1604595471" --header "Connection: keep-alive" "https://c-s.net.ua/forum/ipb.html?act=attach&type=post&id=40051" -L -o 'cstrike_amxx_1_8_2_fix.zip' &&\
    unzip -q cstrike_amxx_1_8_2_fix.zip &&\
    cd cstrike_amxx_1_8_2_fix &&\
    cp cstrike_amxx_i386.so /home/cs/cstrike/addons/cstrike/dlls &&\
    echo "linux addons/cstrike/dlls/cstrike_amxx_i386.so" >> /home/cs/cstrike/addons/metamod/plugins.ini &&\
# ReGameDLL
    cd /home/Resources/regamedll &&\
    mkdir /home/cs/cstrike/addons/regamedll &&\
    curl --header "Host: c-s.net.ua" --header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36" --header "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" --header "Accept-Language: ro-RO,ro;q=0.9,en;q=0.8" --header "Referer: https://c-s.net.ua/forum/topic81470.html" --header "Cookie: _ga=GA1.3.1603347949.1602960053; __gads=ID=f426b07af5c143a1-22526794ffb800af:T=1603190043:RT=1603190043:S=ALNI_MaFPky-pOiwPIbZanyNiU0Ksdqm0Q; _gid=GA1.3.999712779.1604595471; session_id=1176d37d74d1a5cf21577ccba8e1f55d; topicsread=a%3A4%3A%7Bi%3A17628%3Bi%3A1603190043%3Bi%3A84615%3Bi%3A1604596752%3Bi%3A81470%3Bi%3A1604348492%3Bi%3A74614%3Bi%3A1603821602%3B%7D" --header "Connection: keep-alive" "https://c-s.net.ua/forum/ipb.html?act=attach&type=post&id=45156" -L -o 'ReGameDLL_CS_publish_5.3.0.217_artifacts.zip' &&\
    unzip -q ReGameDLL_CS_publish_5.3.0.217_artifacts.zip &&\
    unzip -q regamedll-dist-5.3.0.217-dev.zip &&\
    cp bin/bugfixed/cs.so /home/cs/cstrike/dlls &&\
    cp game.cfg /home/cs/cstrike &&\
# ReAimDetector
    cd /home/Resources/reaimdetector &&\
    curl --header "Host: c-s.net.ua" --header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36" --header "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" --header "Accept-Language: ro-RO,ro;q=0.9,en;q=0.8" --header "Referer: https://c-s.net.ua/forum/topic84615.html" --header "Cookie: _ga=GA1.3.1603347949.1602960053;__gads=ID=f426b07af5c143a1-22526794ffb800af:T=1603190043:RT=1603190043:S=ALNI_MaFPky-pOiwPIbZanyNiU0Ksdqm0Q; session_id=b83b284a0cf31d151d82a2dd7600f65d; topicsread=a%3A4%3A%7Bi%3A17628%3Bi%3A1603190043%3Bi%3A84615%3Bi%3A1603916003%3Bi%3A81470%3Bi%3A1603477078%3Bi%3A74614%3Bi%3A1603821602%3B%7D; _gid=GA1.3.252331836.1603916004; _gat=1" --header "Connection: keep-alive" "https://c-s.net.ua/forum/ipb.html?act=attach&type=post&id=47508" -L -o 'reaimdetector_0.2.2.rar' &&\
    unrar x reaimdetector_0.2.2.rar &&\
    cp -r linux/addons /home/cs/cstrike/ &&\
    echo "reaimdetector" >> /home/cs/cstrike/addons/amxmodx/configs/modules.ini &&\
    cd /home/cs/cstrike/addons/amxmodx/scripting &&\
    ./amxxpc reaimdetector.sma &&\
    cp reaimdetector.amxx /home/cs/cstrike/addons/amxmodx/plugins/ &&\
    echo "reaimdetector.amxx" >> /home/cs/cstrike/addons/amxmodx/configs/plugins.ini &&\
# Cleaning
    rm -rf /home/Resources &&\
# Run server
    cd /home/cs/ &&\
    screen -A -m -d -S cs /home/cs/hlds_run -game cstrike +maxplayers 25 +map de_dust2 -autoupdate -pingboost 3" >> /home/cs/start.sh
```

The last screen command doesn't run when I start the container but when I enter in the container and run the exact same command it does run.
The dockerfile builds an Counter-Strike 1.6 Server with reHLDS.

Edit: After I've tried ti7 method when I run the container it gives me this error :

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"start.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

This is the code I've tried :

```
echo "#!/bin/sh" >> /home/cs/start.sh &&\
    echo "# start.sh" &&\
    echo "screen -A -m -d -S cs /home/cs/hlds_run -game cstrike +maxplayers 25 +map de_dust2 -autoupdate -pingboost 3" >> /home/cs/start.sh &&\
    chmod +x /home/cs/start.sh &&\
    /home/cs/start.sh
WORKDIR /home/cs/
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/cs/start.sh"]
```

This is the command I run the image with :

```
sudo docker run -itd -p 27015:27015/udp --name=cs cstrike /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screen is created before the container is finished

Directly set commands which should start with the container when it begins into the `ENTRYPOINT` or a script which it calls

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# start.sh
screen screen_command

# exec the final command replacing this script with the new process
# this makes the new process the forefront in Docker, keeping the container
# running until it exits and allowing signals to be passed (such as ^C)
exec sleep infinity
```

```
...
RUN generate_script.sh
WORKDIR /home/cs/
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/cs/start.sh"]
```

With an `ENTRYPOINT`, you don't need to specify any shell when running the container
Arguments passed after the name will be sent to the container and can be interpreted by the script [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312311/4541045)

```sh
docker run --detach --init --name foo-name container
```

Comment: `CMD` is probably better.

Comment: I've had mixed experience and I recall `ENTRYPOINT` is more convenient to pass arguments to (though that may not or may no longer be the case)

Comment: @Zeth ah, you should call it with a full or relative path - I've updated my answer too

Comment: does it work? the layers should be cached

Comment: @ti7 now the container exists after 1 sec

Comment: @Zeth you've posted that twice now after deleting it; do you mean *exists* or *exits*?

Comment: I thought you didn't got that, sorry for typo... exits..

Comment: @Zeth no problem! hmm.. add a line to keep it open at the end of your entrypoint script - I'll update my Answer again

Comment: @ti7 If I write exec sleep infinity the image will no longer be built.

Comment: @Zeth I think your troubles come from identifying what is "in the image" vs what "runs when the image is started" - the image must contain stuff which the base system isn't guaranteed to have in it (some directories and CS 1.6 in your case), and when it runs, start your program and block exiting until it is complete (which for you is never, so you manually close the image). If you run your program in a screen (which is not necessary), then the main process continues and exits once its logic is complete. Blocking the process from ending is then necessary to keep the image from exiting.

Comment: @ti7 thx for help and also thx for downvote (I think it was you), after I removed RUN generate_script.sh works like a charm :)

Comment: @Zeth excellent and not I! If this solved your question, please mark it as the Answer with the green check at its left!