# Passing a url and path to a directory to a docker

Tags: python, docker, containers

I have a python script `python_fun.py` and going to prepare a docker file for it, the code needs a directory and a url for downloading some data. I am wondering how I can pass the url path. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727594/how-to-pass-arguments-to-shell-script-through-docker-run) question I designed the docker as below:

in the `python_fun.py` I have:

```
def do_somthing(url, dir_path):
    #do something!

if __name__=="__main__":
    dir_path = sys.argv[1]
    url = sys.argv[2]
    do_somthing(url, dir_path)
```

I made a shell script as below

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts 'i' OPTION; do
    case $OPTION in
        i) dir_pth=$OPTARG;;
        
    esac
done
python python_fun.py $4 $dir_pth
```

In the dockerfile I call the bash script as below:

```
RUN bash test.sh  -i /module/testdata/results/
```

and am going to build and run the docker using the below commands:

```
docker build -t myaccount/docker_name:latest .
```

But it gives me `list index out of range` issue in the python script, any idea to fix it?

Comment: Can you use the standard Python library [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and do the command-line parsing in the Python application itself, getting rid of the shell-script wrapper?  That would have one layer fewer (and avoid the shell-quoting bugs you currently have).

Comment: thanks for the reply, how could I change the dockerfile then? `RUN python python_fun.py -i /module/testdata/results/ 
`

Comment: You shouldn't need to spell out `python` if the `python_fun.py` script is executable and starts with the "shebang" line `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.